# Clicking "my logins" when preferences is open does nothing

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, login

1. Go to https://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/17174#
2. Go to "preferences"
3. Click "my logins"
4. Nothing happens

Comment: Is it just killing you that you can't fix it anymore?

Comment: Nice to see you.  We've been awfully short on waffles lately.

Comment: Confirmed. -----

Comment: Works for me.  Browser?  Popup blocker?

Comment: @Robert you need to be in the preferences tab

Comment: Ah, what do you know.  Nothing happens.

Comment: I wonder if waffles left this bug here intentionally so he could come back a year later and cash in on the unicorn dollars?

Comment: Yup, the bug is only in the preferences tab. I was gonna post this more like 3 weeks ago, if I wasn't blocked :(

Comment: Nice talk last month by the way Waffles, was fun to watch

Comment: thanks all, sorry I have been so busy I have not found much time for meta lately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, so the page was missing an include and, without javascript loaded, a bunch of things were broken.

Nick Craver fixed it, and it should be live soon.